# python socket server transfering empty files with http protocol

Tags: python, sockets, http, networking, server

I've started to learn networks programming using python and I've got some problem with my server.

I'm trying to build a simple one that can represent simple server with some images, js and css but I can't figure out what is the problem with my file transfer code, so after I google it for over an hour I gave up.
I'm checking through the browser, It's sending the html pretty well but at the upper part of the page there is JS code. when I tried to request images alone the browser downloaded "name_I_choose.jpg" file, but it was 0kb file.

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import os

print "server on"
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 80))
server_socket.listen(10)
while True:
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    try:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        # print data
    except socket.error:
        print "no more requests, bye"
        break
    if not data:
        break
    lines = data.split("\r\n")
    print lines[0]
    parts = lines[0].split(" ")
    print "1: " + parts[0] + " 2: " + parts[1] + " 3: " + parts[2]
    if parts[0] == "GET" and parts[2] == "HTTP/1.1":
        print "good"
        if parts[1] == "\\" or parts[1] == "/":
            path = "path/to/root/index.html"
        else:
            path = "path/to/root" + parts[1].replace("\\", "/")
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            f = file(path, 'rb')
            size = b = os.path.getsize(path)
            print size
            types = {"txt": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "html": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "jpg": "image/jpeg",
                     "js": "text/javascript; charset=utf-8", "css": "text/css"}
            f_type = types.get(path.split(".")[1])
            data = f.read(size)
            print "sending data"
            client_socket.send("HTTP/1.0 200 " + str(size) + "\r\n" + "Content-Type: " + f_type)
            client_socket.send(data)
        else:
            print "file not found"
            print path
            client_socket.send("HTTP/1.0 404 -1\r\n")
    else:
        print "not GET HTML FORM"
    break
print "done"
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

There are probably lot of problems so I will appreciate everything you will suggest. Thanks :)

Comment: can you include some output when you run this code? helps.

Comment: can you please be more specific? what kind of output?

Comment: sorry -- i mean output from this program. you run this program as a server and then you attempt to fetch files from it, right? what output so you see from the running server? i see print statements in your code -- can you show us that output? how are you fetching data from this running server?

Comment: here is the output when I just tried to get 127.0.0.1 on my browser:                          server on
GET / HTTP/1.1
1: GET 2: / 3: HTTP/1.1
good
path/to/file/index.html
25592
sending data
done

Comment: Its the output for 127.0.0.1/path/to/image.jpg: server on
GET /imgs/abstract.jpg HTTP/1.1
1: GET 2: /path/to/image.jpg 3: HTTP/1.1
good
path/to/root/path/to/image.jpg
37193
sending data
done

Comment: @matiaselgart ?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I solve it, turns out that the problem was with the file reading.
The right operation is:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as infile:
            d = infile.read(1024)
            while d:
                try:
                    client_socket.send(d)
                except socket.error, msg:
                    print "socket error occurred: ", msg
                d = infile.read(1024)
```